# Regex for 1-10 in javascript for validation

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the regex for numbers ranging 1-10 and 1-5? Please help this troubled soul.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with a regex in the first place?

Comment: Why use a regular expression for numeric range testing?

Comment: I need to validate input from the user for my textbox. The valid values before submitting the form is 1-10 for 1 field and 1-5 for another. Something like var validrange= /^[0-9]/; or something but I need the correct format!!

Comment: @ValianthX So use `parseInt()` and check for `1 ≤ n ≤ 10`

Comment: Regular expressions are not the right tool for this. Use normal number comparison.

Comment: @Phil - also check for "isNaN()" ...

Comment: @Pointy You can check but a numeric comparison with `NaN` will return false anyway

Comment: Ah well that's true.  It might be nice to know the difference between an out-of-range error and a not-a-number error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could achive that with easy number checks in javascript:

```
// Convert input to integer just to be sure
mynum = parseInt(mynum, 10);

// Check number-range
if(mynum >= 1 && mynum <=10)
and
if(mynum >= 1 && mynum <=5)
```

If you really want to use regex:

```
/^([1-9]|10)$/
and
/^[1-5]$/
```

*UPDATE*:

- Fixed the first regex to correctly match the string boundings
- Added parseInt to the first example to ensure correct number-checks

Comment: also the first regex matches 0. :-)

Comment: `parseInt()` (capital I) should be given the radix argument. `parseInt( mynum, 10 )`

Comment: The regex is still not accurate. The `^` only applies to the first alternative, and the `$` only to the `10`. So `5555` would match, as would `xxxxx10`.

Comment: You want to drive me nuts, do you? :) Thanks for the input

Answer (score 4):

This is not a good use of Regular Expressions.

Use simple conditions:

```
if (x > 0 && x < 6) {
  // x is 1 - 5
}

if (x > 0 && x < 10) {
  // x is 1 - 10
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For 1-5 you only need to enclose it as character class:

```
  /^[1-5]$/
```

For 1-10 you'd just need an additional alternative:

```
  /^([1-9]|10)$/
```

Comment: What if the input is given as "03", or "3.0"?

Comment: @patrick: Both are supposed to fail that test. If an integerish or floatish comparison is required instead of a string format verification, then a regex is too much effort.

Comment: Considering that it is for validation (presumably of user input), I'd say that those possibilities should be given consideration, and I'd agree that *"a regex is too much effort"*.

Comment: @patrick: I would say it's too much effort if really done as Javascript verification. If this was to be used as `<input pattern=` regex however, it might very well save some typing. (But so would type=number with min= max=)

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you want to use regular expressions?

```
/([1-9]|10)/
```

Answer (score 1):

For 1-10 it can be

```
/^([1-9]|10)$/
```

and for 1-5 simply

```
/^[1-5]$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use numeric comparison. The following Number extension can check if a number falls between 2 values:

```
Number.prototype.between = 
  function(lower,upper, includeBoundaries){
    lower = Number(lower);
    upper = Number(upper);
    noCando = isNaN(lower) || 
              isNaN(upper) || 
              lower>=upper;
    if ( noCando ) {
      throw 'wrong arguments or out of range';
    }
    return includeBoundaries
           ? this >= lower && this <= upper
           : this > lower && this < upper
};
// usage:
(12).between(1,12); /=> false
(12).between(1,12,true); /=> true
(12).between(0,15,true); /=> true
(0).between(-5,1); //=> true
```

The function converts the parameters to Number because 0 can evaluate to a boolean in javascript, to be able to check if the paramaters are real number values and to be able to check if lower is not greater than/equal to upper. In those cases an error is thrown.

The `includeBoundaries` parameter also checks if a Number is equal to lower or upper, if it's not supplied, the function returns a real 'between'-check.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be

```
/^([1-9]|10)$/
```